# MYSQL fast search by two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains ids and emails. For simplicity's sake lets say that an id is the row number. Both of these columns are unique - no two rows will have the same id and no two rows will have the same email. I need to be able to query fast id by email and email by id.

If I were to program this schema myself, in addition to the main table (which is indexed by the id), I would store a hash table which would have the emails as the keys. That would ensure O(1) for searches in both directions.

Here is how I plan on making my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE main_table (
    id      INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email   VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
            ...
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
    UNIQUE(email)
);

CREATE TABLE id_by_email (
    email   VARCHAR(256),
    id      INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(email),
    FOREIGN KEY(email) REFERENCE main_table(email),
    FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCE main_table(email),
);
```

Will this setup even work? And if it will, will it produce the O(1) lookup I'm striving for?

Comment: *I need to be able to query fast id by email and email by id.* The fastest method is in create indices by `(id, email)` and by `(email, id)`. These indices are covering and does not need in accessing the table body for data retrieving.

Comment: That's much better than what I had in mind. So there is no need for the id_by_email table. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The search in a B-tree index is `O(log n)`.  For all practical purposes, this is fast enough.  After all, the log of 1,000,000 is only about 30.

In addition, with an index, you don't have to worry about whether or not a hash table fits into memory.  And SQL maintains the index even when the data changes.

Comment: So will the setup I described above work? I mean will the lookup of an email in id_by_email take O(log n).  I am asking because I don't know whether having a key that is both primary and foreign will have any effect on the search algorithm.

Comment: @RoyVaron . .  Yes, but you should use an integer id, especially if you are concerned about performance.